# Adding the number of unique decision variables in the objective function.

Tags: notation, linear-programming, integer-programming

In a linear program formulation, my objective function requires to add the number of unique decision variable it took. (in my original problem, unique decision variable may reduce cost).

Let's say I have 3 decision variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$. They are all integers and between 1 to 5.

The objective function will be:

$$
min\ ax_1+bx_2+cx_3 + D
$$

Here I need this term $D$ to add the number of unique decision variable. For example, if we are checking $3,5,4$ as $x_1, x_2, x_3$ then $D = 3$. However for $3,4,4$, $D$ will be 2.

Is there any way I can incorporate this in my objective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,5\}$, let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether $x_i=j$.
For $j \in \{1,\dots,5\}$, let binary variable $z_j$ indicate whether $x_i=j$ for some $i$.  The problem is to minimize $$a x_1 + b x_2 + c x_3 + \sum_{j=1}^5 z_j$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_j y_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_j j y_{i,j} &= x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
y_{i,j} &\le z_j &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$}
\end{align}

Comment: This answer is spot on. Why did someone give it a down-vote??

Comment: @RobPratt That's a great solution. I wouldn't have probably figured it out myself. Just a question, isn't 3rd constraint is redundant? What problem it may cause if we remove it? (just curious)

Comment: Without the third constraint, the solver would return $z_j=0$ for all $j$.